# Upgrading OS with DRBD in use

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

I have 2 servers using DRBD 8.4.3 for database replication & HA via Corosync, and I'm prepping to do an OS upgrade on these two servers soon.

I am wondering if anyone has done an OS upgrade with DRBD in use, and if so what I should prep for prior to pushing ahead with the OS upgrade. I'll be upgrading via `do-release-upgrade` on 14.04, so I'll be going through the gamut of 14.04 -> 16.04, then 16.04 -> 18.04.5 as the stopping point.

Comment: Upgrading from an EOL release to another EOL release will be ... inadvisable. If 18.04.5 is the goal for multiple systems, it may be better for your sanity if you install 18.04 fresh then bring your DRBD configuration and data over as part of a backup-restore validation process ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)